# Populate an excel sheet column with directory files using OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I have an excel workbook with two WorkSheets, "Tourist Information" and "Documents". In the "Documents" sheet, I have to fill the "Scanned Document" column with all the file names found in a directory. I don't have to fill any other column except Scanned Document column. I am unable to fill the excel sheet with file names which start from cell reference C3. Could you please help me to populate the column with file names.

**"Documents" Sheet is:**

[image]

**My code is:**

```
//Open the Excel file in Read Mode using OpenXML
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\TouristRecord.xlsx", true))
{
    WorksheetPart documents = GetWorksheetPart(doc.WorkbookPart, "Documents");
    Worksheet documentsWorksheet = documents.Worksheet;
    IEnumerable<Row> documentsRows = documentsWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

    //Loop through the Worksheet rows
    foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\DocumentsFolder"))
    {
        foreach (Row row in documentsRows)
        {                           
            // I am unable to write logic to update the excel sheet value here.
        }
    }
    doc.Save();
}
```

And GetWorksheetPart method is :

```
public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
{
    string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name)).Id;
    return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a cell to C3 you will need to create a new `Cell` object, assign it a cell reference of C3, set its value and then add it to the `Row` that represents row 3 on the sheet. We can wrap that logic into a method like this:

```
private void AddCellToRow(Row row, string value, string cellReference)
{
    //the cell might already exist, if it does we should use it.
    Cell cell = row.Descendants<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CellReference == cellReference);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new Cell();
        cell.CellReference = cellReference;
    }
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
    row.Append(cell);
}
```

If we assume that the current worksheet has a contiguous set of rows then the logic of what to write is pretty straightforward:

- Iterate each row in the document
- Check if the row index is greater than 2 (as you want to start writing from 3 onwards). If it is:

  - Grab the 3rd `Cell` or create it if it doesn't exist.
  - add the nth element of your file list to the `Cell`.
  - Increment n
- Iterate the remaining files in your file list (as you may have more files than rows in the original document). For each one:

  - add a new `Row`
  - add a new `Cell` to the `Row` with the file name as the cell's value.

Putting that into code you end up with:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\TouristRecord.xlsx", true))
{
    WorksheetPart documents = GetWorksheetPart(doc.WorkbookPart, "Documents");
    //get the she sheetdata as that's where we need to add rows
    SheetData sheetData = documents.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
    IEnumerable<Row> documentsRows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
    //get all of the files into an array
    var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\DocumentsFolder");

    if (filenames.Length > 0)
    {
        int currentFileIndex = 0;

        // keep the row index in case the rowindex property is null anywhere
        // the spec allows for it to be null, in which case the row
        // index is one more than the previous row (or 1 if this is the first row)
        uint currentRowIndex = 1;

        foreach (var documentRow in documentsRows)
        {
            if (documentRow.RowIndex.HasValue)
            {
                currentRowIndex = documentRow.RowIndex.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                currentRowIndex++;
            }

            if (currentRowIndex <= 2)
            {
                //this is row 1 or 2 so we can ignore it
                continue;
            }

            AddCellToRow(documentRow, filenames[currentFileIndex], "C" + currentRowIndex);

            currentFileIndex++;

            if (filenames.Length <= currentFileIndex)
            {
                // there are no more files so we can stop
                break;
            }
        }

        // now output any files we haven't already output. These will need a new row as there isn't one
        // in the document as yet.
        for (int i = currentFileIndex; i < filenames.Length; i++)
        {
            //there are more files than there were rows in the directory, add more rows
            Row row = new Row();
            currentRowIndex++;
            row.RowIndex = currentRowIndex;

            AddCellToRow(row, filenames[i], "C" + currentRowIndex);
            sheetData.Append(row);
        }
    }
}
```

There's an assumption above that the current worksheet has a contiguous set of rows. This might not always be true as the spec allows for empty rows to not be written to the XML. In that case, you could end up with gaps in your output. Imagine the original file has data in rows 1, 2 and 5; in that scenario the foreach would cause you to skip writing to rows 3 and 4. This can be solved by checking the `currentRowIndex` inside the loop and adding a new `Row` for any gaps that may occur. I haven't added that code as it's a complication that detracts from the fundamentals of the answer.